# Error PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express

Buenas, tengo una REST API hecha en NodeJS y ExpressJS y el problema que estoy teniendo es que al pasar varias horas sin hacerle ningún request, la conexion a MYSQL se cierra, entonces al volver a hacer una request la conexion esta cerrada, me tira ese error y aunque la API sigue corriendo no funciona ninguna consulta a la db que desee hacer hasta que la reinicie. Vi algo de handleDisconnect y pool pero no he logrado que nada funcione, ademas de esto tambien me gustaria que si intencionalmente o por cualquier cosa el servidor de mysql se cierra tampoco crashee la API por `connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306`. Simplemente que intente conectarse en silencio hasta que el servidor de MYSQL este disponible denuevo y se conecte. Hasta se podria loguear un mensaje pero no que la API se caiga.

Server.js

```js
REST.prototype.connectMysql = function() {
    var self = this;
    var pool      =    mysql.createPool({
        connectionLimit : 100,
        waitForConnections : true,
        host     : process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME,
        user     : process.env.RDS_USERNAME,
        password : process.env.RDS_PASSWORD,
        database : process.env.RDS_DB_NAME,
        debug    :  false,
        wait_timeout : 28800,
        connect_timeout :10
    });

    pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
        if(err) {
          self.stop(err);
        } else {
          self.configureExpress(connection);
        }
    });
}

REST.prototype.configureExpress = function(connection) {
      var self = this;
      app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
      app.use(bodyParser.json());
      var router = express.Router();
      app.use('/api', router);
      var rest_router = new rest(router,connection,md5);
      self.startServer();
}

REST.prototype.startServer = function() {
      app.listen(3000,function(){
          console.log("All right ! I am alive at Port 3000.");
      });
}

REST.prototype.stop = function(err) {
    console.log("ISSUE WITH MYSQL n" + err);
    process.exit(1);
}

new REST();
```

Un endpoint de REST.js

```js
    router.get("/users/one/:id", function(req,res){
        var query = "SELECT * FROM ?? WHERE ?? = ?";
        var table = ["users", "id", req.params.id];
        query = mysql.format(query, table);
        connection.query(query,function(err,rows){
            if(err) {
                console.log(err)
                res.json(err);
            } else {
                res.json(rows);
            }
        });
    });
```